# Передать date в fragment

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте все перечитал не могу понять как правильно передать значение даты в коде выделю. Те что выводятся в textview  передаются а те что без не получается. Что делаю не так? НЕ СУДИТЕ СТРОГО НОВИЧОК(((

```
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.preference.PreferenceManager;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;


public class ftab1 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    private TextView datestartkyr;
    private  TextView dateFinishkur;
    private TextView zastavka;
    private TextView zastavkaingl;

    private TextView Period211;
   private TextView Period111;
  private TextView Period311;


    private SharedPreferences sharedPrefskyr;
    public static final String myPrefskyrOne = "myprefstartkyr";
    public static final String myPrefstartkyr = "myprefstartkyr";
    public static final String myPreffinishkyr = "mypreffinishkyr";

    public static final String nameper11kyr = "nameKey33kur";
    public static final String nameper22kyr = "nameKey44kyr";
    public static final String nameper33kyr = "nameKey55kyr";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ftab1, container, false);


        datestartkyr = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dateAndTime);
        long dateStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf111 = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd MMM yyyy");
        String dateStringStart = sdf111.format(dateStart);
        datestartkyr.setText(dateStringStart);
//С ЭТОГО МЕСТА ---

        long date2 = System.currentTimeMillis()+ (8 * 86400000);
        SimpleDateFormat p = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd MMM yyyy");
        String dateX = p.format(date2);
        Period111.setText(dateX);


        long date3 = System.currentTimeMillis()+ (15 * 86400000);
        SimpleDateFormat N = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd MMM yyyy");
        String dateY = N.format(date3);
        Period211.setText(dateY);


        long date4 = System.currentTimeMillis()+ (19 * 86400000);
        SimpleDateFormat Nc = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd MMM yyyy");
        String dateJ = Nc.format(date4);
        Period311.setText(dateJ);

//ДО ЭТОГО МЕСТА Я ПОНИМАЮ ЧТО НЕ ПРАВИЛЬНО

        dateFinishkur = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dateandFinish);
        long dateFinish = System.currentTimeMillis()+ (21 * 86400000);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf333 = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd MMM yyyy");
        String dateStringFinish = sdf333.format(dateFinish);
        dateFinishkur.setText(dateStringFinish);


        // при старте проверяем есть ли в файлах настроек
        // данные по ключу nameKey
        sharedPrefskyr = getActivity ().getSharedPreferences(myPrefskyrOne, 0);
        if (sharedPrefskyr.contains(myPrefstartkyr)) {
            // если есть, то ставим значение этого ключа в EditText
            datestartkyr.setText(dateStringStart);

        }
        if (sharedPrefskyr.contains(nameper11kyr)) {
            Period111.setText(dateX);
        }
        if (sharedPrefskyr.contains(nameper22kyr)) {
            Period211.setText(dateY);
        }
        if (sharedPrefskyr.contains(nameper33kyr)) {
            Period311.setText(dateJ);
        }
        if (sharedPrefskyr.contains(myPreffinishkyr)) {
            // если есть, то ставим значение этого ключа в EditText
            dateFinishkur.setText(dateStringFinish);
            //вывод сохраненного периода
            getText();
        }


        //  button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        // button.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);


        zastavka = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        zastavkaingl = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        Button button1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button999);
        Button button2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button333);
//

        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);



        return view;
    }

    // метод для сохранения текста в файл настроек
    public void getAndSave() {
        // получаем текст
        String editTextValue = datestartkyr.getText().toString();
        String editTextValue2 = dateFinishkur.getText().toString();
        String editTextValue3 = Period111.getText().toString();
        String editTextValue4 = Period211.getText().toString();
        String editTextValue5 = Period311.getText().toString();

//Передаем
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefskyr.edit();
        // сохраняем по текст из EditText по ключу nameKey
        editor.putString(myPrefstartkyr, editTextValue);
        editor.putString(myPreffinishkyr, editTextValue2);
        editor.putString(nameper11kyr, editTextValue3);
        editor.putString(nameper22kyr, editTextValue4);
        editor.putString(nameper33kyr, editTextValue5);
        editor.commit ();
    }
    // метод для получения текста из SharedPreferences по ключу
    public void getText() {
        sharedPrefskyr = getActivity ().getSharedPreferences(myPrefskyrOne, 0);
        if (sharedPrefskyr.contains(myPrefstartkyr)) {
            datestartkyr.setText(sharedPrefskyr.getString(myPrefstartkyr, ""));
        }
        if (sharedPrefskyr.contains(myPreffinishkyr)) {
            dateFinishkur.setText(sharedPrefskyr.getString(myPreffinishkyr, ""));
        }
        if (sharedPrefskyr.contains(nameper11kyr)) {
            Period111.setText(sharedPrefskyr.getString(nameper11kyr, ""));
        }
        if (sharedPrefskyr.contains(nameper22kyr)) {
            Period211.setText(sharedPrefskyr.getString(nameper22kyr, ""));
        }
        if (sharedPrefskyr.contains(nameper33kyr)) {
            Period311.setText(sharedPrefskyr.getString(nameper33kyr, ""));
        }
    }


    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.button999:
                getAndSave ();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity (), "Дата сохранена", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                zastavka.setText("КОНТРОЛЬ ИНКУБАЦИИ ЗАПУЩЕН!");
                zastavkaingl.setText("The program is running!");
             startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity3.class));
                break;

            case R.id.button333:


                long dateStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
                SimpleDateFormat sdf111 = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd MMM yyyy");
                String dateStringStart = sdf111.format(dateStart);
                datestartkyr.setText(dateStringStart);

                long dateFinish = System.currentTimeMillis()+ (21 * 86400000);
                SimpleDateFormat sdf333 = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd MMM yyyy");
                String dateStringFinish = sdf333.format(dateFinish);
                dateFinishkur.setText(dateStringFinish);
           //     datestartkyr.setText("");
          //      dateFinishkur.setText("");
         //      startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity3.class));
                Toast.makeText(getActivity (), "Текущая дата", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            zastavka.setText("КОНТРОЛЬ ИНКУБАЦИИ ОСТАНОВЛЕН!");
            zastavkaingl.setText("A CONTROL INCUBATION IS STOPPED!");

              break;


    }


    }





}
```

Comment: Не могли бы вы подробнее описать свою проблему, чтобы и человек, который о ней ничего не знает, тоже мог понять, в чем именно она заключается. Что должно происходить при выполнении кода и что происходит на самом деле.

Answer (score 0):

В выделенном периоде, не корректны обращения к TextView
Может я чего-то не вижу, но ты устанавливаешь текст для

```
  private TextView Period211;
  private TextView Period111;
  private TextView Period311;
```

хотя ни один из них не проинициализирован и должен быть npe
при попытке сделать **setText** на **null** объекте
нехватает

```
Period211 (TextView) = view.findViewById(R.id.типаАйДи);
Period111 (TextView) = view.findViewById(R.id.типаАйДи);
Period311 (TextView) = view.findViewById(R.id.типаАйДи);
```

Comment: Спасибо я сделал так и работает только вопрос правильно ли

Comment: ` Period111 = new TextView(getActivity ());
        long date2 = System.currentTimeMillis()+ (8 * 86400000);